# Easy way to find the Yesterday's date using Perl modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm currently using below code to find the yesterday's date.

Is there any alternative/easy way to do that?

**code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;

my $YesterdaysDate = spGetYesterdaysDate();
print "$YesterdaysDate\n";

sub spGetYesterdaysDate {
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime();
my $yesterday_midday=timelocal(0,0,12,$mday,$mon,$year) - 24*60*60;
($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime($yesterday_midday);
my @abbr = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
my $YesterdaysDate = sprintf "%s %02d %4d", $abbr[$mon], $mday, $year+1900;
return $YesterdaysDate;
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `my $t = localtime() - ONE_DAY;`